# Meta slider is not working error: $(...).flexslider is not a function

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

I am using with meta slider plugin. I created new slider and used the short code. but the meta slider is not working and is giving this error:

> TypeError: $(...).flexslider is not a function

I've tried many solutions but the problem is still the same. Here is [link](https://www.manresa-sj.com/about-us/#top)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you are including the FlexSlider JS file *before* jQuery. As FlexSlider relies on jQuery, this causes the error you're seeing.

To fix this, put the `<script>` tag that references FlexSlider *after* the one for jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

delete the plugin.reinstall the plugin by downloading it as zip file and upload the plugin instead of directly installing the plugin.I had the same issue and got resolved by doing so.